# Activity not finishing immediately while setVideoUri called

Tags: java, android

I have a video view in my activity and when user press play i used

```
 videoView.setVideoURI(uri);
 video.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {

    public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
         progressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
          mp.start();
       }
    });
```

this works fine and i have a button to stop and exit from the screen were i used `videoView.stopPlayback();finish();` but the activity onDestroy() not called immedialy and if start the Activity again that stuck until the pevious onDestroy called

Answer (score 0):

When you open that activity set that flag on intent like

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Login.this, Dashboard.class);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
startActivity(intent);
```